# What Math/Calculator software is available for the iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, applications

I just saw [Pi Cubed](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/picubed), and now I'm thinking, what Math/Calculator apps are available for iPod Touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The best calculators for iOS:

- [Wolfram Alpha](http://products.wolframalpha.com/iphone/)
- [PCalc](http://www.pcalc.com/iphone/)
- [Calcbot](http://tapbots.com/software/calcbot/)
- [Soulver](http://www.acqualia.com/soulver/iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

I use [wolfram alpha](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wolframalpha/id334989259?mt=8). its a great app for computing basically anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you love the old-school reverse-polish-notation (RPN) HP calculators, like I do, then check out [i41CX](http://www.alsoftiphone.com/i41CX/). It's an iOS emulator for the HP-41CX calculator, and is very faithful (except for having *way* more memory than the original): for example, synthetic programming is supported. I have not found an HP-48 emulator for iOS yet.

I have i41CX+ installed on my (second-generation) iPod Touch. It's probably overkill for the uses I have for a calculator these days, but it works the way I expect a calculator to work.

Answer (score -1):

I use (and rate) Missing Calculator, although by the looks of things it isn't in the App store (UK) any more..